# Modal window in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a table in a HTML file. It is populated from JSON.

Inside one of the cells I want to include a link that should open a modal window.

It works fine, but I want to show on this modal window information about the table row where the link is included.

This is part of the code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
        <td>{{data.material_number}}</td>
        <td>{{data.material_name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.material_price}}

         <a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

            <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
                <div>
                    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                    <h2>{{data.material_name}}</h2>
                    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
                    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>

                </div>

            </div>

        </td>
        <td>{{data.currency_name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.material_price_date}}</td>
        <td>{{data.unit_name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.provider_name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.material_active}}</td>

        <td><a href="edit_material.php?id={{data.id_material}}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My problem is that inside the H2 tag that is shown in the modal window, the data from {{data.material_name}} are not the data from the selected row, but the data from the first row in the table.

Any help is welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the rendered links to make sure you're getting the right value for data.id_material (which looks fine to me).  What are you using for the modal?  Is it UI Bootstrap?  If so can you post your modal controller code?

Comment: Thank you @squillman, all other links inside the row are working fine. If I put a link at the same TD but outside the DIVs it also shows the expected data.x

Comment: @squillman, this is what am I using for the modal: http://plnkr.co/edit/UaUA1VHDQl8x9yErAJKU?p=preview

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect it's a scope thing.  Try giving each div a unique id (instead of all of them being `openModal`).  Something like `id="openModal{{data.id_material}}"`.

Comment: @squillman, I will try your proposal...thank you

Comment: @squillman, if I change the id for the first div, then the modal window doesn't open.

Comment: You would also have to change the href for the Open Modal link to `href="#openModal{{data.id_material}}"`

Comment: @squillman, doesn't work either...

Answer (score 1):

HTML Code: Try using ng-click and passing the row data as a parameter as follows

```
  <a ng-click="openModal(data)">Open Modal</a>

        <div id="openModal" ng-show="showModal" class="modalDialog">
            <div>
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                <h2>{{modaldata.material_name}}</h2>
                <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
                <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.openModal = function(data){
  $scope.showModal = true;
  $scope.modaldata = data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Naitik, but your proposal doesn't work either.